# Как пропустить действие не используя try except?

Tags: python

Как мне избежать ошибку и прогнать следующее значение в цикле? Когда в img_list нет файла срабатывает try except и переходит к следующему действию, заполняется text, но так как у меня нечего вкладывать в параметр photo выскакивает ошибка, если в параметре photo нет файлов ,мне как то нужно пропустить действие с url

```
    for pi in img_list:
           
        try:
            url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id=%d&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (
                    group_id, vk_key)   
            resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']
            upload_url = resp['upload_url']
            files = {'file1': open(pi, 'rb')}    
        except Exception:                 
            print(f"Что пошло не так с постом id {post_id}")
    
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=%s&from_group=1&message=%s&attachments=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % \
                  (-group_id, text, photo, vk_key)
     
    resp = requests.get(url).json()
    print(resp)
```

Comment: Для начала исправь отступы. Потом объясни так, чтобы было понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед циклом установите переменную в `None`, а после цикла проверяйте удалось ли в цикле ее значение установить:

```
photo = None
for pi in img_list:
       
    try:
        url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id=%d&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (
                group_id, vk_key)   
        resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']
        upload_url = resp['upload_url']
        files = {'file1': open(pi, 'rb')}    
        photo = ...
    except Exception:
        print(f"Что пошло не так с постом id {post_id}")

if photo: 
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=%s&from_group=1&message=%s&attachments=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % \
              (-group_id, text, photo, vk_key)
 
    resp = requests.get(url).json()
    print(resp)
```

Comment: Уже пробовал выдает ошибку variable 'photo' referenced before assignment

Comment: Ну так в этом коде `photo` значение нигде и не присваивается. Если никакой ошибки не случилось, и раньше  `photo` ничего не присвоили, то конечно будет такая ошибка. Только это к сформулированному вопросу (о пропуске обработки при ошибке) не относится :)

Comment: это из за try except оно у меня после переменной files если нет не каких файлов в pi то код дальше не сработает

Comment: url нужно выносить за цикл иначе постятся одинаковые фото

Comment: Я не смог распарсить ваш комментарий, попробуйте со знаками препинания. Еще раз повторю, в коде нет присвоения переменной `photo`. Если у вас другой код, не такой как в вопросе, то ничего не подскажу, что-то неправильно в нем, нужно его показать, чтоб можно было что-то комментировать.

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало.